# Use Python __repr__() for 2D List

Tags: python, oop, multidimensional-array

Is there a way to make `__repr__()` return a 2d list so that it prints row by row in Python?

My attempt is below. I can't see how I can insert `new lines`, like in `print("..", end="\n")`.

```
class Board:
    def __init__(self, rows = 6, cols=7, fill=0):
        self.rows = rows
        self.cold = cols
        self.symbol = fill
        self.board = [[fill] * cols for row in range(rows)]

    def __repr__(self):
        return str([self.board[i] for i in range(len(self.board))])


board = Board()
print(board)
```

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be using `__repr__()` for this use – let's call it `.format()` instead, maybe?

Either way, you'll want to generate lines out of the characters with no separator (`''.join(...)`), then join those lines with `'\n'`:

```py
def format(self):
    return '\n'.join([''.join(str(c) for c in row) for row in self.board])
```

Comment: `__str__` is fine; `format` would probably carry the connotation that it is related to the `format` method supported by the `str` type.

Comment: Well, sure. `__str__()` would work, but `__repr__()` feels wrong for this.